# Sudoku crashes when game starts

Tags: android

Hi I am a beginner to android and I am doing a basic sudoku application to study android and finds myself stuck when i start the game..APP CRASH..!!!!
Whenever I try to start the game it crashes and takes me back to the menu screen in my emulator.Someone please help me on this..

Thanks in advance.

The following is my code:

puzzleview.java

```
package org.example.sudoku;

public class puzzleview extends View {
private static  final String TAG="SUDOKU";

private float width;
private float height;
private int selX;
private int selY;
private final Rect selRect= new Rect();

private final Game game;

public puzzleview(Context context){
    super(context);
    this.game=(Game) context;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w,int h,int oldh,int oldw){
width = w/9f;
height = h/9f;
getRect(selX, selY, selRect);
Log.d(TAG, "onSizeChanged width " + width +", height "+ height);
super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
}

private void getRect(int selX2, int selY2, Rect selRect2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
Paint background=new Paint();
background.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_background));
canvas.drawRect(0,0, getWidth(), getHeight(), background);


Paint dark = new Paint();
dark.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_dark));

Paint hilite = new Paint();
hilite.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_hilite));

Paint light = new Paint();
light.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_light));


for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
canvas.drawLine(0, i * height, getWidth(), i * height,
     light);
canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height
     + 1, hilite);
canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(),
     light);
canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1,
     getHeight(), hilite);
}
for(int i=0; i<9; i++){
if(i%3!=0)
  continue;
canvas.drawLine(0,i*height,getWidth(),i*height,dark);
canvas.drawLine(0, i * height + 1, getWidth(), i * height
      + 1, hilite);
canvas.drawLine(i * width, 0, i * width, getHeight(), dark);
canvas.drawLine(i * width + 1, 0, i * width + 1,
      getHeight(), hilite);
}

Paint foreground = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
foreground.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.puzzle_foreground));
foreground.setStyle(Style.FILL);
foreground.setTextSize (height * 0.75f);
foreground.setTextScaleX(width/height);
foreground.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);

FontMetrics fm=foreground.getFontMetrics();
float x=width/2;
float y=height/2 - (fm.ascent+fm.descent)/2;

for(int i=0;i<9;i++){

 for(int j = 0;j<9;j++){

Line 95 ---->:   canvas.drawText(this.game.getTileString(i, j), i
             * width + x, j * height + y, foreground);

      }
 }
}
}
```

logcat:

```
06-09 10:51:30.163: E/AndroidRuntime(2266):     at      org.example.sudoku.puzzleview.onDraw(puzzleview.java:95)
```

Comment: Also, please post *the entire stack trace*.

Comment: @jbabey canvas.drawText(this.game.getTileString(i, j), i
     * width + x, j * height + y, foreground);

Answer (score 1):

It depends how you are using your view, but if you are using it in XML then you need to add another constructor

```
public puzzleview(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
    super(context, attrs);
    this.game=(Game) context;
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
}
```

Comment: @zamilnizar do u plan to point out line 95 or should we count ?

Comment: @Siddharth please read the earlie comments i mentioned the thread above:
    06-09 12:07:21.541: E/AndroidRuntime(2519):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2797)

Comment: how about posting the entire stack trace

Comment: I read the entire article, and I still wont count to 95. And without the entire stack, you are waiting everyones time. How many more times do you need the same thing requested.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine that line 95 accesses something which hasn't been initialised. When the app. starts it will quite probably try and render puzzleview. At a guess, `game` hasn't been fully initialised at this point, and so the access to `game.getTileString(i, j)` fails in some way. You might like to have a flag in `Game` which tells `puzzleview` when `getTileString` is ready to be used, which you use in `puzzleview.onDraw()`:

```
if (game.getTileStringsAvailable()) {
    for (int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for (int j = 0;j<9;j++){
            canvas.drawText(this.game.getTileString(i, j), i * width + x, j * height + y, foreground);
        }
    }
}
```